# MongoDB E11000 duplicate key error on mydb.testlookup.$name dup key:{:dummy123} in meanstack using angular-fullstack generator

Tags: mongodb, angular-fullstack

Hi I am trying to create a simple project using angular-fullstack generator I have running my MongoDB and nodejs in windows, everything installed and running perfectly. I have created one schema as follows

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var TestlookupSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  ccode: String,
  description: String,
  info: String,
  active: Boolean
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Testlookup', TestlookupSchema);
```

I didn't touch any other default schemas that comes along with generator demo app.
whenever I am inserting any record into this collection I am getting below error

```
    E11000 duplicate key error index:  mydb.testlookup.$name dup key: {:dummy123}
```

I am using windows 7 as operating system 
NodeJS 4.xx
Mongodb 3.x

What might be causing this error?

Comment: There is one duplicate document `name: dummy123` in the Testlookup collection... Clear the old collection may solve your issue.

Comment: Apply @zangw said or if you want to allow duplicate records for name field remove the uniqueness on index of name.

Comment: yes I had clear the old collection and there is only first record that I am trying to insert into Testlookup collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got same problem but I resolved it by deleting index. Actually when generate angular-fullstack app it will create Thing schema there will be name field and when you create another schema which has same name field, so it will create Index. If you enter same data like in your case "dummy123" in name field for both schemas it will give duplicate key entry index error - E11000

Solution for this if you are in windows 
Gotto Mongo Shell

```
    command prompt - mongo.exe 
                     use mydb
                     db.mydb.getIndexes()
```

You will find name as index just drop and recreate it

```
                     db.mydb.dropIndex( "name")
```

Now you restart your node app using grunt serve you wont get that problem again